# updating record in asp

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I am doing some adding record in asp. But when i run the code i appear ther problem:

> ADODB.Recordset error '800a0cb3'
>
> Current Recordset does not support updating. This may be a limitation
>   of the provider, or of the selected locktype.
>
> /adding.asp, line 14 ( rs1.addnew )

Code:

```
Dim MYSQL
Dim rs1
set conn1 = server.createobject("adodb.connection")
conn1.open "provider = microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0;data source =  C:\Users\nam2611\Documents\My Web Sites\WebSite1\Database3.accdb"
set rs1 = server.createobject("ADODB.Recordset")

MYSQL = "SELECT * FROM customer"

rs1.open MYSQL, conn1
rs1.addnew
rs1.Fields("customerID") = Request.form("custID")
rs1.Fields("Passcode") = Request.form("CPas")
rs1.Fields("customer_name") = Request.form("custname")
rs1.Fields("C_company") = Request.form("compname")
rs1.Fields("Phone_number") = Request.form("phone")
rs1.Fields("email") = Request.form("email")
rs1.Fields("C_adress_1") = Request.form("adress1")
rs1.Fields("C_adress_2") = Request.form("adress2")
rs1.Fields("C_post_code") = Request.form("Postcode")
rs1.Fields("C_Payment_info") = Request.form("payment")
rs1.update
rs1.close
set rs1 = nothing
response.write "added"
conn1.close
```

Is anyone can help me?
Thank you

Comment: You need to open your record set differently. You need to specify the CursorType and LockType. Try "rs1.open MYSQL, conn1, 1, 3"

Comment: @Dai You're joking right?

Comment: @Lankymart the question has been edited since I posted my comment. I've removed it now.

Comment: @Dai Fair enough, I thought your comment was referring to the fact their string variable is named `MYSQL`, didn't notice the original tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below:

```
...
MYSQL = "SELECT * FROM customer"

rs1.CursorLocation=adUseClient
rs1.CursorType=adOpenStatic
rs1.LockType=adLockBatchOptimistic

rs1.open MYSQL, conn1
...
```

Or in numbers:

```
...
MYSQL = "SELECT * FROM customer"

rs1.CursorLocation=3
rs1.CursorType=3
rs1.LockType=4

rs1.open MYSQL, conn1
...
```